# Trouble with nowrap and max-width on an absolutely positioned element

Tags: css, tooltip, css-position, word-wrap

I'm guessing these two attributes don't actually work together, but my situation:

I'm trying to create a tooltip component. My tooltip is positioned absolutely, and as I don't know what the length of the content would be, has no width. So with width-related css, text just forms a tall, skinny column. I tried `max-width`, but on it's own, that does nothing. So I decided to try `white-space: nowrap`, and while it nicely doesn't wrap text, it also doesn't seem to honor max-width in a useful way, with text instead going out of the boundaries of the element.

I can't think of how to solve my problem, if there is a clean solution. I'd like to have an absolutely positioned div that expands to fit it's content until a maximum, at which point it wraps. One suggestion I saw was making the element a flexbox, but from what I can tell, that's not great with IE, so I don't think is viable in my situation. Any advice?

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1.2em;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>[ ? ]</span>
  <div class="info">Any long text can go in here to test what goes wrong with wrapping.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us any code? Maybe the code where you tried to fix the issue? Would be helpful

Comment: @OvidiuUnguru As it's CSS I don't understand the interaction of, I'm not sure what I can show you to show I tried to "fix" it... as I described, I tried a few different attributes, but none are getting the desired effect. I posted the base code, but short of giving the same code 3 times with one attribute difference between them, not sure what to provide.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yodpao see this if this does solve your problem

Answer (score 7):

Avoid using `white-space:nowrap` as that will constrain your text to one line. `max-width` should work with a block level element with display absolute but not inside an inline element. To resolve this, I place the tooltip outside of your wrapper block and use javascript to position it at the mouse location.

Here is a simple solution for your issue. Click on "open tooltip" to display the tooltip and move the slider to change the value of `max-width`.

```js
showContext = function() {
    var e = window.event;

    var posX = e.clientX;
    var posY = e.clientY;
    var info = document.getElementById("info");
    info.style.top = posY + "px";
    info.style.left = posX + "px";
    info.style.display = "block";
}

changeWidth = function(value) {
  var info = document.getElementById("info");
    info.style.maxWidth = value + "px";
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.info {
    position: absolute;
    max-width:300px;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:white;
}

.range {
  margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    max-width slider
    <input id="range" class="range" type="range" min="100" max="600" oninput="changeWidth(this.value)"/>
    <input type="button" value="open tooltip" onclick="javascript:showContext();" />
</div>
<div id="info" class="info">Any long text can go in here to test what goes wrong with wrapping.</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure what your goal is as there are a lot of contradictory things going on. But I'll try and hopefully you can guide me towards your desired solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/q7dyf6xh/

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: run-in;
}

.info {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 200px;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Have a look at this fiddle, as you can see the tooltip now has a max-width. Have a look at what I'm using:

`display: run-in;`: Displays an element as either block or inline, depending on context

`white-space: pre-line;`: Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks

**For a better understanding of how things work look here:**

**white-space**: If you use **nowrap** text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a  tag is encountered!

This said your `max-width` is still working but with nowrap you *overflow* your element now. Try and give your element a `background-color` and you'll see that it actually is only as wide as your `max-width` defines.

See here how it overflows the element: https://jsfiddle.net/fcnh1qeo/

And now width `overflow: hidden` only the text inside your box will be displayed. Everything else is cut off! See here: https://jsfiddle.net/0qn4wxkg/

What I used now is `display: run-in;` and `white-space: pre-line;` as well as `max-width: 200px` which will give you hopefully your desired solution. Not knowing the context and code you using it is more of a guess than it is a answer. But maybe I can guide you towards a solution which fits your needs

Cheers!

Comment: Problem is that `display:run-in` doesn't work on firefox at all

Answer (score 2):

Add a `min-width:100%` and a `white-space: nowrap;`

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
 
.info {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <span>[ ? ]</span>
    <div class="info">Any long text can go in here to test what goes wrong with wrapping.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't make the wrapper a block, as not every element that gets this sort of tooltip will be a block element. The component I'm making is meant to be inline next to other elements, inline-block at best. And that doesn't help when I need to attach such a tooltip to an element directly.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with `display:flex;`? I would do it, but I would need to see more elements to be able to reproduce your bug

Comment: As I mentioned, my concern with flex is IE compatibility. And the concern is not which element it goes on (could be any) but the display of the wrapper as you noted.

Comment: You can try to move the `info` div from the `wrapper` div and give the `info` a `top:0;` or play around with the positioning, this solves the wrapping issue, but you may have other issues

Comment: I tried some more and edited the code, please check if it's alright

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the exact problem I'm trying to fix. As I mentioned, I tried no wrap, and it seems that doesn't honor min-width, which is what I'm trying to do: not have a will width element.

Comment: Hmm, in your original desc it was mentioned max-width, thought min-width would be better

Comment: Not sure how a min-width: 100% helps when I'm trying to not go full width? Maybe if you help explain?

Comment: I tested it some more, and yeah it doesn't help at all. I can't seem to find a proper solution, though if you want to use the inline display. Can you tell me what kind of errors you found with flex on IE? Flex should work fine if you use -ms-flex .

Comment: for me it helped, the min width is always 100% and the max-width is set to a defined value (like 10px) and then it's always 100%, it's dirty as hell but it works

Answer (score 2):

`display="runin"`The element generates a run-in box. Run-in elements act like inlines or blocks, depending on the surrounding elements. That is:
If the run-in box contains a block box, same as block.
If a block box follows the run-in box, the run-in box becomes the first inline box of the block box.
If an inline box follows, the run-in box becomes a block box.

`pre-line` Sequences of whitespace are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.
The following table summarizes the behavior of the various `white-space` values:

The `max-width` CSS property sets the maximum width of an element. It prevents the used value of the width property from becoming larger than the value specified by `max-width.`

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: run-in;
  top: 100px;
 }


.info {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 1.2em;
 left: 0;
 max-width: 200px;
 white-space: pre-line;
 background-color: #ddd;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Not that ling ago i had a very similar problem myself. I fixed it using flexbox what is already suggested in the comments here.

My code looks like this:

```
.has-tooltip {
  display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-start
}

.has-tooltip > .tooltip {
  padding: 1em;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #bdc3c7;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  transform: translate(-50%,-110%)
}
```

I also copied this into [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rud5vnx7/) just in case you want to have a look at it. (:

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that this does not work.

Here's a solution that works if you are allowed to use BR tags.  I have worked on tooltips many times and this is the best solution that I have.

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/btn-ninja/pen/JNJrgp

It works by using white-space nowrap with a css translate:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block hasTooltip">
  Tooltip on top
  <i class="tip">Most tooltips are short<br>but you can add line breaks.</i>
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-block hasTooltip right">
  Tooltip on the right.
  <i class="tip">Tooltip on right<br>vertically centered.</i>
</button>     

.hasTooltip .tip {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%; left: 50%; 
    transform: translateX(-50%); }

.hasTooltip.right .tip {
    bottom: auto; left: 100%; top:50%; 
    transform: translateY(-50%); }
```

The translate allows the absolutely-positioned tooltip to horizontally or vertically center itself vs the content.  White space with a BR achieves wrapping for long content while allowing shorter tooltips to match width of the tooltip text.

Here's the full css:

```
.hasTooltip { 
  position:relative; }

.hasTooltip .tip {
  display:block;
  background: #333; color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size:inherit; 
  font-style:normal;
  line-height: 1rem;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius:4px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .34s ease-in-out;
  white-space:nowrap;  
  z-index:99; }

.hasTooltip .tip:before {
  content: "";
  display:block; position:absolute; left:0; bottom:-5px; 
  width:100%; height:5px; }

.hasTooltip .tip:after {
  border-left: solid transparent 6px;
  border-right: solid transparent 6px;
  border-top: solid #333 6px;
  bottom: -4px;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0; }

.hasTooltip:focus .tip,
.hasTooltip:hover .tip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto; }

.hasTooltip.right .tip {
  bottom: auto; left: 100%; top:50%; transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-bottom:0; 
  margin-left:5px; }

.hasTooltip.right .tip:before {
  left:-5px; bottom:auto; }

.hasTooltip.right .tip:after {
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: solid transparent 6px;
  border-bottom: solid transparent 6px;
  border-right: solid #333 6px;
  bottom:auto; 
  left: -4px;
  top:50%;
  margin-left: 0; 
  margin-top: -6px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `width: max-content` combined with `max-width`.

Eg:

```
.tooltip {
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

The content will now only wrap if it exceeds the max width.

See also: [position: absolute child element - Don't wrap text until max-width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409284/position-absolute-child-element-dont-wrap-text-until-max-width)