# How to specify flexible width for div used as marker on Leaflet map?

Tags: css, leaflet

I have a text field which I want to expand in width to fit the content, but only up to a width of a certain width (200px) - anything wider should wrap to the next line.

I am currently doing this with the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="info">Any long text can go in here to test what goes wrong with wrapping.</div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.wrapper {
   position: relative;
   display: run-in;
}
.info {
   position: absolute;
   max-width: 200px;
}
```

This works fine on its own. But when I use it for the HTML of a Leaflet marker as follows,

```
L.marker(
   [ myLat, myLong ],
   {icon: L.divIcon({
      className: 'my-div-icon',
      html:'<div class=wrapper><div class=label>'+innerText+'</div></div>'}) }
   ).addTo(layerGroup);
```

the result is wrong - it wraps the lines after every single white space. As far as I can tell, this seems to be a result of the `L.icon` property `iconSize` being null by default, so zero becomes the default width of the `<div>`. However, if I manually force `iconSize` to be a larger number (200px), then I see the `<div>` is ALWAYS 200px wide, even if the intended content (`innerText`) is less than 200px, leaving white space on the side.

How can I make the Leaflet marker fit the width of `innerText` if that's <200px, but wrap at 200px if its width is wider?

Comment: not sure that playng around with run-in for display is usefull. Was it from CSS2.1 (1998 ?) and implemented in ? ,  yep, remind us which browser once implemented it ? ?

Comment: `width:max-content; max-width:200px;` maybe this could be an hint ?

Comment: Tried it. For text<200px, it displays perfectly. For text>200px, it wraps at 200px. However, if the longest wrapped line is 175px long, then ideally the size would 175px not 200px. So definitely an improvement, but not perfect...

Comment: This was my reference (answer by  floGalen):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949322/trouble-with-nowrap-and-max-width-on-an-absolutely-positioned-element/46002787

Comment: And while I'm dreaming, the absolute optimum would be "if text<200px, display in box sized to fit the text. if 200px<text<400px, wrap at the midpoint of the text, so both lines are of similar length, and the box is of minimal size. if 400px<text<600px, do same on three lines. etc"

Comment: hello, maybe you can sort something out of this https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mddjyKx  (max-content + width:xx%) , but looks like only javascript could help you here.

Comment: ^ Doesn't seem to work :( Starting to look like Javascript is my only option...