# position: absolute child element - Don't wrap text until max-width?

Tags: html, css

I've searched related questions and haven't found a proper solution in any of the questions to this problem, is this still impossible in 2020...?

I have a parent `A` position relative with a child `DIV` position absolute.

The child DIV shows on hover (a tooltip), but the problem is that the text seems to wrap way earlier than what the DIV's max-width allows for.

Essentially, I believe it tries wrapping to the parent's width for some reason.
`white-space: nowrap` expands the text properly, but then it won't wrap after reaching `max-width` either, of course.

```css
#mydiv {
  width:250px;
  background: #fee;
  margin: 150px; /*just for demo purposes*/
}
#mydiv a {
  position: relative;
}
#mydiv a div {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  bottom: calc(100% + 1px);
  background: #eee;
  max-width: 300px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* white-space: nowrap; */ /*toggle me*/
}
#mydiv a:hover div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <a href="#">
    <div>
      Here is an example tooltip text
    </div>
    Test link
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `position:absolute` is limited by its containing block width. You can consider negative value for left/right to expand the div past this limitation. Any big value will do the job, it simply need to be the same for both.

```css
#mydiv {
  width:250px;
  background: #fee;
  margin: 150px; /*just for demo purposes*/
}
#mydiv a {
  position: relative;
}
#mydiv a div {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  bottom: calc(100% + 1px);
  background: #eee;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin:0 auto; /* Don't forget this for centring */
  left:-300px;
  right:-300px;
}
#mydiv a:hover div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <a href="#">
    <div>
      Here is an example tooltip text Here is an example tooltip text Here is an example tooltip text
    </div>
    Test link
  </a>
</div>

<div id="mydiv">
  <a href="#">
    <div>
      Here is an example
    </div>
    Test link
  </a>
</div>
```

Or like below if you want to keep the shrink-to-fit behavior of the tooltip

```css
#mydiv {
  width:250px;
  background: #fee;
  margin: 150px; /*just for demo purposes*/
}
#mydiv a {
  position: relative;
}
#mydiv a div {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  bottom: calc(100% + 1px);
  background: #eee;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin:0 auto;
  left:-300px;
  right:-300px;
  width:max-content; /* addedd this */
}
#mydiv a:hover div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <a href="#">
    <div>
      Here is an example tooltip text Here is an example tooltip text Here is an example tooltip text
    </div>
    Test link
  </a>
</div>

<div id="mydiv">
  <a href="#">
    <div>
      Here is an example
    </div>
    Test link
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good attempt, but I believe the tooltip will always stretch out to its max-width of 300px, even if there is less text inside, which isn't what I need.

Comment: ```width: max-content``` did the job, thanks a lot!

Comment: Just perfect! `width: max-content` did the trick to me. Awesome! Thank you very much!

Answer (score -2):

Hope this help :)

Here is solution

```css
#mydiv {
   width: 250px;
    background: #fee;
    margin: 150px;
}
#mydiv a {
  position: relative;
  display:block;
}
#mydiv a div {
      position: absolute;
    display: none;
    bottom: calc(100% + 1px);
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
#mydiv a:hover div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <a href="#">
    <div>
      Here is an example tooltip text
    </div>
    Test link
  </a>
</div>
```